# angular4,typescript,MVC5 - Getting 404 error to html template files

Tags: angular, typescript

I have my components in `/app/Component/` folder and my HTML files are in `/app/HTML/` folder. my component declaration is as below

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-header',
    templateUrl: '/app/HTML/header.html'

})
```

It works well on local when run from Visual Studio. However after hosting on a virtual directory in IIS it is taking a different path by omitting Virtual directory from the path and getting 404 error.

Sorry to paste this lengthy error

```
(index):31 http://localhost/VirtualDirectory/
zone.js:2969 GET http://localhost/app/app.component.html 404 (Not Found)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:2969
ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:407
Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:255
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone @ zone.js:1114
(anonymous) @ zone.js:3001
proto.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1394
ResourceLoaderImpl.get @ resource_loader_impl.ts:57
DirectiveNormalizer._fetch @ compiler.es5.js:14083
DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplateOnly @ compiler.es5.js:14129
DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplate @ compiler.es5.js:14111
CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata @ compiler.es5.js:15144
(anonymous) @ compiler.es5.js:26838
(anonymous) @ compiler.es5.js:26837
JitCompiler._loadModules @ compiler.es5.js:26834
JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents @ compiler.es5.js:26803
JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync @ compiler.es5.js:26729
PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone @ application_ref.ts:333
PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule @ application_ref.ts:371
(anonymous) @ main.ts:9
(anonymous) @ main.ts:9
(anonymous) @ main.ts:9
evaluate @ evaluate.js:106
(anonymous) @ instantiate.js:359
dynamicExecute @ register-loader.js:665
doEvaluate @ register-loader.js:612
ensureEvaluate @ register-loader.js:520
(anonymous) @ register-loader.js:133
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
Zone.run @ zone.js:138
(anonymous) @ zone.js:872
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:595
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:578
ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410
Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:252
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:862
resolvePromise @ zone.js:808
(anonymous) @ zone.js:724
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1042
ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:891
Ctor.then @ zone.js:1041
resolvePromise @ zone.js:775
(anonymous) @ zone.js:873
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:595
```

Comment: Try using proper relative paths - https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Comment: Just wondering, why do you keep your `.ts` and `.html` files of the same component in separate directories? Isn't it making the structure less well-organized?

Comment: It is helping me to differentiate files properly

Comment: Got it, thanks for the answer. Btw, giving relative paths should fix your problem. Giving `../HTML/header.html`  instead of `/app/HTML/header.html`

Comment: Your file structure is a bit odd. It may help you if you had your files grouped together. Check out the angular documentation. https://angular.io/guide/file-structure

Comment: if starting a path with '/' the angular shall expect the path to be an absolute path starting from application root. On the live server it means the path shall start from root url e.g. www.example.com. Use relative paths or change the base APP_BASE_HREF to the virtual directory folder so that absolute paths start from their onwards.

Comment: No Luck. I tried all options